# PHP fopen not working in IBM Bluemix

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, fopen

I have this php code in Bluemix server:

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    $myfile = fopen("uploads/ac/1.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "John Doe\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    $txt = "Jane Doe\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
 ?>
```

When I access this php page via url, it shows me this error :

```
Unable to open file!
```

I guess its something to with options.json file or permissions but can't figure out what. 
The same code works fine on localhost. Please help.

Comment: Do you have the relevant permissions to open this file? Does this file exists?

Comment: @Dekel I did not either do any permissions settings nor the file exists.

Comment: Do you have the upload/ac folders? if not - create them

Comment: @Dekel And even for the localhost, I had to run sudo <directoryname> 777.

Comment: i dont understand if there is still a problem there or not

Comment: So, I guess it can also be permissions issue

Comment: Even after adding upload/ac folder, i am getting same `Unable to open file!` message

Comment: Did you check php-log for errors?